# Anti-debugger technique: How to hide a thread from the debugger using VB.NET?

Tags: c++, vb.net, debugging, reverse-engineering, translate

For several days, I have been trying to document myself about Anti-Debugger techniques.

So I found many different methods to achieve this. In these techniques, I found the possibility to **hiding** thread from debugger, thanks to the NtSetInformationThread method.  **My project is to use this method in my code written in VB.NET.**

Here is a description of the technique I found in my research, which I find very well explained:

> In Windows 2000, a new class of thread information transferred to the
> NtSetInformationThread function appeared – ThreadHideFromDebugger.
> This was one of the first anti-debugging techniques provided by
> Windows in Microsoft's search for how to prevent reverse engineering,
> and it's very powerful. If this flag is set for a thread, then that
> thread stops sending notifications about debug events
>
> [From this website](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/367-anti-reverse-engineering-protection-techniques-to-use-before-releasing-software)

So I found a source coming from this [site](https://www.ivanlef0u.tuxfamily.org/?p=48) to achieve this.
Here is the method he uses in C++:

```
typedef enum _THREADINFOCLASS {

    ThreadHideFromDebugger=17

} THREADINFOCLASS;

extern "C" ULONG __stdcall NtSetInformationThread(
    __in HANDLE ThreadHandle,
    __in THREADINFOCLASS ThreadInformationClass,
    __in_bcount(ThreadInformationLength) PVOID ThreadInformation,
    __in ULONG ThreadInformationLength
);

ULONG main()
{
    ULONG Status;

    Status=NtSetInformationThread(GetCurrentThread(), ThreadHideFromDebugger, NULL, 0);

    if(Status)
        printf("Error with NtSetInformationThread : 0x%xn", Status);

    __asm {int 3}
    return 0; 
}
```

So I tried with my beginner knowledge in C++ to translate this code (To be honest I do not really know much about this language).
Here's what it gave:

```vb
Private Declare Function NtSetInformationThread Lib "Ntdll.dll" (ByVal hThread As Long, ByVal ThreadInformationClass As Long, ByVal ThreadInformation As Long, ByVal ThreadInformationLength As Long) As Long
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")>

Public Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As UInteger
End Function

Shared Function HideFromDebugger() As UInteger
    Dim Status As UInteger

    Status = NtSetInformationThread(GetCurrentThreadId(), 17, Nothing, 0)

    If Status <> 0 Then

        Console.Write("Error with NtSetInformationThread : 0x{0:x}n", Status)
        Debugger.Break()
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

However, I feel like I'm wrong somewhere. For example, I do not understand what the argument "17" is for. Could you tell me if I'm on the right track?

Each answer items are very valuable to me :)

Comment: You might like to check if your code is being run under a debugger by calling [IsDebuggerPresent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent), and quietly exit if so.

Comment: There is not only one anti-debugger technique. IsDebuggerPresent is the best known, but its field of action is different. The site I mentioned, https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/367-anti-reverse-engineering-protection-techniques-to-use-before-releasing-software, lists many.

Comment: `17` is the value of `ThreadHideFromDebugger` and doesn't really have any special source or meaning. It simply tells `NtSetInformationThread()` _what_ information to change about the thread.

Comment: On a side note your P/Invoke declaration for the `NtSetInformationThread` function is not quite correct. It should actually be `(ByVal hThread As IntPtr, ByVal ThreadInformationClass As Integer, ByVal ThreadInformation As IntPtr, ByVal ThreadInformationLength As UInteger) As Integer`. Also do favour `DllImport` over `Declare Function`. The latter is a relic from VB6. :)

Comment: It should be noted that the enum declaration you show is almost certainly a cut-down version of the full enum to only include the particular member that you need.  The entire point of the enum is to give meaning to the `17` so that it's not just a magic number.

Comment: Fun fact: Every anti debugger technique or any obfuscation technique you come up with is going to be defeated by a sufficiently determined attacker. So seriously; Don't bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but your current code has two issues:

First of all your P/Invoke declaration for the `NtSetInformationThread` function is not quite correct and I recommend you stick to `DllImport` as most `Declare Function` declarations that you find on the internet were written for VB6 and are not compatible with VB.NET.

Here is the corrected version:

```vb
<DllImport("Ntdll.dll")>
Public Shared Function NtSetInformationThread(ByVal hThread As IntPtr, ByVal ThreadInformationClass As Integer, ByVal ThreadInformation As IntPtr, ByVal ThreadInformationLength As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function
```

Secondly, notice how the C++ code uses the function `GetCurrentThread()` and *not* `GetCurrentThreadId()`. These two are different in that the former gets you a handle which is more like a pointer to the thread, whereas the latter just gets you a numeric ID assigned to the thread.

You need to use the `GetCurrentThread` function instead:

```vb
<DllImport("Kernel32.dll")>
Public Shared Function GetCurrentThread() As IntPtr
End Function
```

> I do not understand what the argument "17" is for.

`17` is the value of `ThreadHideFromDebugger` and doesn't really have any special source or meaning. It simply tells `NtSetInformationThread()` what information to change about the thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at my code. I understand better my mistakes now, I would have to use more the documentation of `NtSetInformationThread` :) You explain well. Still hoping that my code actually fulfills its function

Comment: @MarshallCocop : Glad I could help! I've tested the code on my end and breakpoints and such stop working after calling `NtSetInformationThread`, so it appears to be doing what it should.

Comment: Yes perfect so! :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in case of any want wants the C# version

```
    [DllImport("Ntdll.dll")]
    public extern static uint NtSetInformationThread(IntPtr hThread, int ThreadInformationClass, IntPtr ThreadInformation, uint ThreadInformationLength);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

    public static void DisableantiDebug()
    {
        NtSetInformationThread(GetCurrentThread(), 17, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    }
```